# html FORMS || formdata || AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, form-data

starting point: I have a site with multiple forms like this:

```
<form class="form card-content-ingredients" action="" id="form-id-0" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <ul>
              <li class="form__item">
                <label class="form__label" for="name">Text</label>
                <input class="form__input form__input--textfield" type="text" name="description" value="" placeholder="description">
              </li>
              <li class="form__item">
                <label class="btn btn--invalid" for="file" >picture</label>
                <input class="form__input form__input--file" id="file" type="file" name="img" value="picture">
              </li>
              <ul class="form__item--multi-align-right">
                <li>
                  <input class="btn btn--invalid" type="button" value="cancel">
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input class="btn btn--invalid btn__save" type="button" value="Save" data-item-id="0" data-rqstPath="/xyz">
                </li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </form>
```

When I click save an **AJAX request** is made transferring all data in a FormData interface including the file.

**My problem is: only the file from the first form element is getting transferred.** For all other forms the **file input** field is not included when I click save, but strangely all other input fields. When I change the order of the forms, it still has the same effect. 
I only use one JS function dealing with the formdata, which looks like this:

```
function updateSettingsAJAX( itemID, rqstPath) {

        if (!(typeof itemID !== typeof undefined && itemID !== false) ||
            !(typeof rqstPath !== typeof undefined && rqstPath !== false)) {
            return false;
        }

        var formData = new FormData($('#form-id-' + itemID)[0]);


        formData.append("itemID", itemID);

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: rqstPath,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        });
```

If someone could help me with my problem, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Do you have duplicate ID's on those file inputs? Are they all `file`?

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Thanks you @thebluefox, that fixed my problem!!

Comment: I've posted an answer @ArtemisUser to close the question - glad I could help :)

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here. If you found an answer to your question then either post it and accept it or delete the question

Comment: @ArtemisUser - please accept a correct answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Posting on behalf of OP after my suggestion in the comments;

Duplicate ID's on the file `<input>` caused a problem whereby label's triggering input fields always triggered the first field.

As an aside - it's an old standard but one still worth adhearing to - [ID's must be unique](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score -1):

This is your code, with some corrections (unic IDs in forms), and it works fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/sk5j8qds/

```
<form class="form card-content-ingredients" action="" id="form-id-0" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<ul>
    <li class="form__item">
        <label class="form__label">Text</label>
        <input class="form__input form__input--textfield" type="text" name="description" value="" placeholder="description">
    </li>
    <li class="form__item">
        <label class="btn btn--invalid" for="file_0" >picture</label>
        <input class="form__input form__input--file" id="file_0" type="file" name="img" value="picture">
    </li>
    <ul class="form__item--multi-align-right">
        <li>
            <input class="btn btn--invalid" type="button" value="cancel">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="btn btn--invalid btn__save" type="button" value="Save" data-item-id="0" data-rqstpath="/echo/html/">
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

```
<form class="form card-content-ingredients" action="" id="form-id-1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
        <li class="form__item">
            <label class="form__label">Text</label>
            <input class="form__input form__input--textfield" type="text" name="description" value="" placeholder="description">
        </li>
        <li class="form__item">
            <label class="btn btn--invalid" for="file_1" >picture</label>
            <input class="form__input form__input--file" id="file_1" type="file" name="img" value="picture">
        </li>
        <ul class="form__item--multi-align-right">
            <li>
                <input class="btn btn--invalid" type="button" value="cancel">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="btn btn--invalid btn__save" type="button" value="Save" data-item-id="1" data-rqstPath="/echo/html/">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</form>
<script>
function updateSettingsAJAX( itemID, rqstPath) {
        if (!(typeof itemID !== typeof undefined && itemID !== false) || !(typeof rqstPath !== typeof undefined && rqstPath !== false)) {
            return false;
        }

        var formData = new FormData($('#form-id-' + itemID)[0]);


        formData.append("itemID", itemID);

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: rqstPath,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        $('.btn__save').on('click', function () {
            return updateSettingsAJAX($(this).data('item-id'),$(this).data('rqstpath') );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should provide more details on your changes it would help @ArtemisUser review your answer